# Refactoring this PartialView (saving current action name in .cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, razor

I have a `PartialView` which extensively uses `ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue`, here's a snippet:

```
 <div class="@(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "AddQuestion" ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem")">
              @Html.ActionLink("Add a Question", "AddQuestion", new { topicId = ViewBag.topicId })</div>
 <div class="@(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "AddSubTopic" ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem")">
                @Html.ActionLink("Add (Sub) Topic", "AddSubTopic", new { topicId = ViewBag.topicId })</div>
 <div class="@(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString() == "AddResource" ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem")">
                @Html.ActionLink("Add a Resource", "AddResource", new { topicId = ViewBag.topicId }) </div>
```

And it goes on like that...
Can I just save the action name in the .cshtml? (saving it in the ViewBag doesn't seem natural to me, as the information is available in the .cshtml itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@{ var actionName = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString(); }

<div class="@(actionName == "AddQuestion" ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem")">
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Question", "AddQuestion", new { topicId = ViewBag.topicId })</div>
<div class="@(actionName == "AddSubTopic" ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem")">
...
```

but it would probably be cleaner to create a HtmlHelper

```
public static HtmlString CssClassForAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string action) {
  var actionName = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
  return new HtmlString(actionName == action ? "selectedItem" : "unselectedItem");
}
```

and in your view

```
<div class="@Html.CssClassForAction("AddQuestion")">
@Html.ActionLink("Add a Question", "AddQuestion", new { topicId = ViewBag.topicId })</div>
<div class="@Html.CssClassForAction("AddSubTopic")">
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did as you suggested which was very educative